# How to fix 'The type or namespace name could not be found ' error in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, scriptable-object

I am setting up a new scriptable object in Unity 5 and when I am trying to set up a reference to it an error shows up :'The type or namespace name 'ES' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?'

the scriptable object script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "new ES", menuName = "ES")]

public class LAMP: ScriptableObject {
    public int groupNum;

    void Start() {

        groupNum = 1;

    }

}
```

the reference in monobehavior script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Bout: MonoBehaviour {

    public ES et;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a name space error ,if you are using a collision variable you face this error.

Using My.Players.namespace;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just had this error and this is the top SO post about it, so I'll post my fix here:

We introduced unit tests, which require the `.asmdef` for each "group" of related scripts. In this particular instance for us, the original developer had the `.asmdef` file for scripts that were contained in an AutoGenerated folder (ROS messages) that was set to be ignored by Git.

He pushed the code, Git ignored the `.asmdef` file for the AutoGenerated files, and then because we were using `.asmdef` files and that folder wasn't included on MY box, my Unity "couldn't find" the files there.

This *could* be your problem, too, but 99 times out of 100 you get this error because you've misspelled the class name - capitalization matters! In OP's case specifically the actual class is `LAMP` even though it's called `ES` in the AssetMenu. Instead of `public ES et;` OP should have had `public LAMP et;` and then it would work.

Answer (score 0):

In your file Bout.cs you are trying to create the variable 'et' of type ES but the type ES doesn't exist, you may want to create a LAMP?

```
public class Bout: MonoBehaviour {
public LAMP et;

// Use this for initialization
void Start() {
```

Creating a scriptable object file named ES (fileName = "new ES") doesn't mean it's type is ES, it takes the type of the class i.e LAMP

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same error while trying to add script component to the gameobject on runtime. Fixed it by following this format:

```
GameObject.AddComponent(typeof(namespace.className));
```

Answer (score -2):

The meaning of `The type or namespace name 'xxxx' could not be found` is because you are trying to use a class that do not exist or you are not using the namespace where that class is.

The problem that you have is that you are trying to use something that do not exists.

You are trying to create a scriptable object named ES, but it's totally different to create a class named ES.

If you create the class ES you will see that the error goes away.